# Does HERE map getRoutingService() v8 return list of coordinates?

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I am using HERE maps to calculate routes but I use Google maps to display the route. In v7 `getRoutingService` used to return

```
result.response.route[0].shape
```

which is an array of coordinates which I pass to google services to draw it on map.

Here is how it looks in V7:

```
 var router = hServicePlatform.getRoutingService();               
 router.calculateRoute(
   routingParameters,
   function (result, err_extras) {
     const routeShape = result.response.route[0].shape; // coordinates array
     show_routePolyline(routeShape); // this draws the polyline on Google maps
   }
  );
```

Using HERE v8, `getRoutingService` doesnt seem to return any coordinates at all. Is there a way to get the coordinates in V8?

Answer (score 1):

An encrypted polyline can be returned using the polyline function however this then needs to be decoded to output meaningful co-ordinates.

Referenced in the Migration guide here.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/migration_guide/index.html